# How to call another function on changing the time range selector and date selector in Highcharts stock?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts, react-highcharts

I am using stock Highcharts where I have a time range selector and date selector. I want to call another function on the change of time range selector and date selector. How can I do that?

Here's the Highchart stock code:

```
    Highcharts.stockChart("config", {
  chart: {
    alignTicks: false
  },

  rangeSelector: {
    selected: 1
  },

  title: {
    text: "Summary"
  },

  series: series
});
```

};

Here's the image:
[image]

I have pointed the time range selector and From - To date selector in the above image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your needs use `setExtremes` or `afterSetExtremes` event callback function:

```
    xAxis: {
        events: {
            setExtremes: function(e) {
                ...
            },
            afterSetExtremes: function(e) {
                ...
            }
        }
    }
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/j0acLf8v/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/xAxis.events.setExtremes

https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/xAxis.events.afterSetExtremes

Comment: Hi @shalu j, I just tested it and it works.

Comment: I don't know, it's not working for me. But thanks for the answer, somehow I got a way to use callback in setExtremes.